# Opening Google Earth kmz files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.18, kmz

I've build an image overlay in Google Earth, but I want to add some other layers via QGIS. In QGIS 2.18.15 on Windows 10, the kmz files just open by adding a raster layer. But...they're clearly wrong. The information in the doc.kml file appears to be a bounding box and the display in QGIS looks like the aspect ratio is wrong, as if the rotation parameter was completely ignored.

So what's the magic to make this work? I have no idea where to start on this and my Google-fu trying to find an answer has failed me.

-- Additional info

I'm trying to add a couple of images, but they're not showing up...

Here is the Google Earth Overlay. Note that aspect ratio of the image.

[Google Earth Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYjcH.jpg)
[image: Google Earth Overlay]

Here's what happens when I load the kml into QGIS:

[QGIS KML Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb2NY.jpg)
[image: QGIS KML Load]

The aspect ratio is wrong, and I really expected north to still be "up".

-- Edit

The QGIS CRS is EPSG:4326. I think I tried forcing EPSG:3857 based on something I found elsewhere about Google Earth, but there is no visible different. If I add the north arrow to QGIS, it points straight up, aligned with the image. Not that the original map is an orienteering map so the north lines on it are in fact magnetic north. What I was aiming for was to pull it into QGIS after getting it calibrated via Google Earth so I could layer a UTM grid over the map.

Here's the doc.kml extracted from the KMZ file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<GroundOverlay>
    <name>Untitled Image Overlay</name>
    <color>66ffffff</color>
    <Icon>
        <href>files/CCI_000001.jpg</href>
        <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
        <north>41.44234537860543</north>
        <south>41.4037612242825</south>
        <east>-73.82018638989426</east>
        <west>-73.85321641890307</west>
        <rotation>13.67718681063408</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

Comment: Hi Roland, welcome to GIS.SE. "clearly wrong" might be clear to you, but we don't see your screen, so could you please provide some screenshots?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post to show the images. The "clearly wrong" is really the aspect ratio and rotation.

Comment: The aspect ratio is probably down to the QGIS using a different projection than Google Earth.  The CRS that you're using ("EPSG:nnnn", in the bottom right of the window) isn't legible in the image you uploaded.  I also notice that, oddly, the north arrow on the map appears to be pointing to grid north in QGIS but not in Google Earth.  As you said though, this could be QGIS not performing the rotation.

Comment: Could you add the contents of the KML file to the question (along with a link to the map image)?

Comment: Regarding the rotation: It looks like the map is oriented to magnetic north in Google Earth but grid north in QGIS.  That strikes me as rather odd; what CRS is QGIS using?

Comment: First off, both WGS 84 (`ESPG:4326`) and Psuedo-Mercator (`ESPG:3857`) will exhibit distortion. Try setting your CRS to `ESPG:32618` (WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N) which will give you a nice, square grid.  Secondly, it's distinctly probable that QGIS's KML driver doesn't support image rotation. One other thing is to make sure you turn on on-the-fly CRS reprojection when you set the project's CRS. Set the KML layer's CRS to WGS 84 (`ESPG:4326`) by right-clicking on the layer and selecting `Set Layer CRS`. BTW,  Psuedo-Mercator (`ESPG:3857`) is a horrible projection and should be used rarely (if ever).

Comment: I know you've put work into this already in getting the map referenced in Google Earth but I'd seriously suggest trying the alternate method I suggested in my answer below.  Yes, you'll need to reference the map again but it should be quicker than trying to get the KML file working correctly.

Comment: Incidentally, `ESPG:32618` (WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N) is the correct CRS for the part of New York that your map covers.

Comment: @AlexHajnal, I've tried getting the Georeferencer to work and it seems to routinely crash when zooming in to place markers. I'll try again with CRS ESPG:32618, I forgot what I tried, it was an eastern NY, but not a UTM zone.

Comment: The crash is almost assuredly to do with the imagery plugin. I shouldn't have suggested the Open Layers plugin; it's rather buggy.  Try the Quick Map Services plugin instead.  WRT the CRS, `EPSG:32618` is a meter-based CRS that pretty much any GPS should support (as `WGS84 UTM` or somesuch).  You may have been using one of the foot-based ones that the State uses for some of their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you might want to consider (now or in future) is to use the Georeferencer plugin in QGIS to do this kind of thing. You can load e.g. Google Maps into a QGIS layer using the Quick Map Services plugin<sup>1</sup> then use the Georeferencer to, well, georeference your image against it. On occasion the plugin can be a bit finicky but over all it works very well.

A [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) for doing this is available.

<sup>1</sup> Using the OpenLayers plugin isn't recommended since it's prone to crashing QGIS

Comment: I've taken this approach and I'm almost there. It's importing as expected. I used the Google Earth overlay to find my reference points to set in the Georeferencer. Now I just need to figure out how to convert the CRS to display as UTM coordinates so I can get my printed map.

Comment: If you've set your project CRS to ESPG:32618 then your map is already using UTM coordinates (in your case `18T eeeeee nnnnnnn`).  To add a visible UTM grid onto your map, take a look at the 2nd and especially the 3rd option I mention in my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/301781/57287

Comment: Well, I clearly don't know what I'm doing. Because the displayed coordinates don't look anything like the UTM format. Probably because I used the wrong units for the georeferencing. Back to square 1.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, it sounds to me like you're doing pretty well.  What is the CRS that your project is currently set to (in the bottom right of the QGIS window)?  If you're set to the CRS I mentioned then the coördinates shown at the bottom of the window should be UTM just without the `18T` prefix.  For example, the map I'm working on right now is in the Adirondacks, just a few hundred km north of the area you're mapping. I'm also using `EPSG:32618` for my project and the coördinate shown on my QGIS window is `591190.8,4887674.6` which (rounded to the nearest meter) is `18T 591191 4887675`.

Comment: @RolandRoberts "don't look anything like the UTM format"  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you.  Is `ZZZ EEEEEE NNNNNNN` not the format you're expecting for UTM? (e.g. `ZZZ`=18T, `EEEEEE`=591191, `NNNNNNN`=4887675 resuting in the UTM coördinate `18T 591191 4887675`)

Comment: @RolandRoberts "[Maybe] I used the wrong units for the georeferencing. Back to square 1."  The georeferenced image you created should be fine.  As long as the CRS of the georeferenced layer matches the CRS that was active when you were doing the georeferencing then it doesn't really matter what the layer's CRS actually is.  If things aren't aligning then maybe you were e.g. using Pseudo-Mercator as your project's CRS when you did the georeferencing.  If that's the case then (in this example) changing the layer's (not the project's) CRS to Pseudo-Mercator would fix things.

Comment: No, I simply misunderstood what I was supposed to enter in the coordinates. I was entering decimal degrees but since the coordinate system is UTM, I should have been entering eastings and northings. Once I did that, everything looks correct. I have some GPX tracks from hiking some of the trails in the area this past weekend which I'll need to load next; they should provide the proof that I've got it correct if they show up on the right places on the map.

Comment: And, since I'm a newbie, my upvote on this answer doesn't count. But this is definitely the way to go. It was a two step process, namely create the Google Earth overlay then use point from that to georeference the image in QGIS. The Google Earth overlay is really just to help find features. You don't want to blindly map points between the two. So I would drop pins, toggle off the overlay and make sure the feature, e.g., a building or road intersection, or something readily identifiable, could be matched with the printed map/jpeg.

Comment: @RolandRoberts Yea, that's the way to go about doing it.  The coordinates are those of the active project CRS.  Remember that if you entered the points using the wrong CRS (e.g. WGS-84 DMS instead of UTM) you can always change the layer's CRS to that of the points you entered.  When you load the GPS tracks don't be surprised if they don't match exactly; both GPS and Google Earth can show half a dozen or more meters variance from actual locations (depending on terrain, etc.).

Comment: @RolandRoberts For NY State, a good resource is https://orthos.dhses.ny.gov/  They have DEMs, better-referenced orthos (ærial imagery), etc.  Click on the 'tools' icon then select 'layers' icon → "Orthoimagery".  If you click the 'tools' icon → 'download' icon you can get links to the WMS servers.  The `WMS` link on the linked page can be used in QGIS (`Layer` → `Add Layer` → `Add WMS/WMTS Layer` → …)

Comment: @RolandRoberts "And, since I'm a newbie, my upvote on this answer doesn't count"  If my answer solved your problem then you can (should) accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon next to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference on the DEM files. I have used NED files before, but the last time I did that was when running on Linux from the command line to make my own contours. I'm going to need to learn how to do this with the Windows toolset.

Comment: I believe there's a port of the usual Unix commandline GIS tools (GDAL, etc.)  to Windows.  Don't recall what it's called though (I do everything under Linux).

Answer (score 0):

I find the **Freehand** Raster Georeferencer plugin to be much easier to use than the Georeferencer plugin.  It also has the benefit of being able to use image formats other than TIFF files, and it can easily export the georeferenced image with a world file that will locate it again if needed.

That avoids the need to involve Google Earth at all.  In fact, it is much like the process you use to locate the image in Google Earth, insert the image, then use the options to move the image, resize it, or rotate it, to get it where you want.

You will need a base map or other layer to use to line it up with (much as you would use Google Earth's satellite images of the Earth to line up your map/image).  In fact, you can load Google's satellite images as a base map in QGIS and use it to align your image with the **Freehand** Raster Georeferencer plugin.

My experience is the **Freehand** Raster Georeferencer plugin can degrade the way an image looks, but, if you export the image with a world file (that is an option with the plugin), you can then open the image in a graphics editor like Paint.net and, being careful to not change the image's dimensions or rotation at all (not one pixel), use it to smooth lines or otherwise improve the image, and then, you can use the world file to load the edited image back in QGIS and it will be as beautiful as you made it in Paint.net/Gimp/Krita/etc.  You need to make sure the file names stay the same for the image and world file as when they were exported.  Pretty painless, and you can get outstanding results.  A possible drawback is you apparently cannot warp an image if that is needed to get it to align properly, but my guess is that is not likely needed unless the image covers a large area on the surface of the Earth.

You can find info on the plugin and how to use it here https://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/ and a search in Google will find tutorials.

Its developer says the plugin has 2 main limitations:

> Blockquote

The lack of support for all the GDAL raster formats: The plugin actually implements its own raster layer that uses Qt to perform reading and only some raster formats are supported (BMP, JPEG, PNG, TIFF).

It only supports affine transformations (without shearing) and not the full set of transformation algorithms (including rubbersheeting) the standard QGIS georeferencer provides.

> Blockquote